# Changes to Input::json() function between Laravel 4 beta3 and beta4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When I was developing in Laravel4 Beta3, I used to get JSON POST data from a service using Input::json() function, But when I updated to Laravel4 Beta4, I am getting following error:

Notice: Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::$productName in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/commonDBAPI/app/controllers/UserController.php line 47

Does any one have any idea, what could be the reason.

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can access just the JSON using `Input::json()->all()`.

JSON input is also merged into `Input::all()` (and `Input::get('key', 'default')`) so you can use the same interface to get Query string data, Form data and a JSON payload.

The documentation does not yet reflect all changes because Laravel 4 is still in beta and the focus is on getting the code right, the documentation will be updated ready for the public release.

---

**How is JSON merged with Input::all()?**

Consider the following JSON:

```
{
    'name': 'Phill Sparks',
    'location': 'England',
    'skills': [
        'PHP',
        'MySQL',
        'Laravel'
    ],
    'jobs': [
        {
            'org': 'Laravel',
            'role': 'Quality Team',
            'since': 2012
        }
    ]
}
```

When merged into Laravel's input the JSON is decoded, and the top-level keys become top-level keys in the input.  For example:

```
Input::get('name'); // string
Input::get('skills'); // array
Input::get('jobs.0'); // object
Input::all(); // Full structure of JSON, plus other input
```

Comment: Uses of Input::json()->all() is straight forward and useful, but how can use Input::all() to get the JSON?

Comment: Input::all() represents all input sent to your script (i.e. query string, form data and JSON payload).  So in an answer you cannot get *just* the JSON from `Input::all()`.  You can still use `Input::get('key', 'default')` to get an individual key.

Comment: ok. But there is no keyname assigned to the JSON payload, so how to use Input::get for that?

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate how JSON is merged with Input, and how you would access this.  Remember, if you just want all the JSON then you can use `Input::json()->all()`.

Comment: I prefer Input::json()->all() as it is easy to use, just a concern, if this will be removed in future versions?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know.  But if it's still there in the stable release next month then I don't see why it will be removed in the future.

Comment: Input::all(), does it return Full structure of JSON ? I tried, but it gives me an empty array. How to access the JSON?

Comment: The only reason that `Input::all()` would not include the JSON is if you're not sending a JSON content type with your payload.  See [isJson()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L425).  `Input::json()` assumes that you have sent JSON and does not check the content type.

Comment: So you are telling that, there is no other way to get JSON payload, other than Input::json()->all(). Input::get('name') - this also doesn't seems to work for me. Did you try this?

Comment: No, I'm telling you that you must send a JSON Content-Type with your JSON payload for Input::all() or Input::get() to recognise the JSON (they both use the same internal process).

You could get the RAW, undecoded JSON using `Input::getContent()` if you want, but you've not asked for this.

Does Input::json()->all() not meet your requirements?

Comment: Beware with postman chromeplugin, it do not send proper ContentType

Answer (score 0):

Yup they changed it to return a ParameterBag object switch your code to Input::json()->all()

Comment: In the official documentation, Taylor has not mentioned about Input::json()->all(). So could it be that, they will change this also? Please find below statement from official documentation: **Some JavaScript libraries such as Backbone may send input to the application as JSON. You may access this data via Input::get like normal.**

Answer (score 0):

For :
{
   "name":"Olivier",
   "title":"Just a try"
}

Try this :

$input = Input::json()->all();

return $input['name'];